# Angular js. Assign Controller with Directive

Tags: angularjs, directive, controllers

I try to connect the controller with the directive in Angular.

Here html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div id='bbb' my-num>Click Me!</div>
</div>
```

I use the *MyCtrl* controller where I define **tegid** and **mytitle**.

```
MainControl.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.tegid = '';
    $scope.mytitle = 'aaa' + tegid;
  }]);
```

Also I have the directive *myNum* in which when hover at  I receive 'id' and I change its contents

```
MainDirectives.directive('myNum', function () {
 return {
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('mouseenter', function () {
        tegid = element.attr('id');
        element.html(mytitle);
    });
 }
};
});
```

Problem in that I can't connect the directive and the controller.
Prompt, please, how to transfer **tegid** to the *MyCtrl* controller?
Why it is impossible to transfer **mytitle** to the directive *myNum*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `tegid` and `mytitle` from the controller socpe to the directive scope, by doing as following:

### Using isolated scope

Directive:

```
directive('myNum', function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      id:    '=',
      title: '='
    },
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('mouseenter', function () {
      // scope.id and scope.title are shared with parent scope via HTML bindings
      tegid = scope.id;
      element.html(scope.title);
    });
  }
};
```

Html:

```
<div id='tegid' title="nytitle" my-num>Click Me!</div>
```

This will create an isolate scope for your directive and is cleaner. However if you don't intend to reuse the directive elsewhere, you can just rely on scope inheritance, which means you'll have access to the parent scope properties:

### Using scope inheritance

Directive:

```
directive('myNum', function () {
  return {
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('mouseenter', function () {
      // scope.teif and scope.mytitle come from the parent scope
      tegid = scope.teid;
      element.html(scope.mytitle);
    });
  }
};
```

Html:

```
<div my-num>Click Me!</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Reference the `$scope` that is passed thru the `link` function:

```
link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('mouseenter', function () {
        $scope.tegid = element.attr('id');
        element.html($scope.mytitle);
    });
}
```